# Can't play audio stream recorded with naudio

Tags: c#, wpf, playback, naudio

I try to record some audio(after Record click button) into a MemoryStream and then Play it in visual studio(WPF) using NAudio. I generated a RawSourceWaveStream that gets the myMemoryStream when click play button but I think this is bugging the code. 
It doesn't play... here is my code.
Where am I go wrong?

```
      namespace RecAndPlay
      {
          /// <summary>
          /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
          /// </summary>
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {
          public MainWindow()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }


        private WaveIn myWaveIn=null;
        private MemoryStream myMemoryStream = null;
        private WaveOut myWaveOut= null;
        private RawSourceWaveStream myRaw = null;
        private void myRecord(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            {
                RecordButton.Content = "Stop Rec";
                myWaveIn = new WaveIn();
                myWaveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
                myWaveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
                myWaveIn.DataAvailable += myWaveIn_DataAvailable;
                myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                myWaveIn.StartRecording();
            }

        }

        void myWaveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {

            myMemoryStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }

        private void myPlay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            myWaveOut = new WaveOut();
            myRaw = new RawSourceWaveStream(myMemoryStream, myWaveIn.WaveFormat);
            myWaveOut.Init(myRaw);
            myWaveOut.Play();


        }

        private void mtStopRec(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myWaveIn.StopRecording();
            RecordButton.Content = "Record";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it got to the myWaveOut.Play(); but after that I can't here anything. And when standing with the mouse on myRaw I can see that it was filled with a buffers but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `Position` on your `MemoryStream` to 0 before playing the audio. Also, bear in mind that with this solution you should not attempt to play while you are still recording.